# Running tomcat in upstart and tracking correct PID in the script

Tags: pid, rhel, upstart, rhel6

I have an `upstart` script that is used to start apache tomcat on an RHEL 6.8 system. The upstart script is as follows

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
    exec >/root/Desktop/test.debug 2>&1
    exec su -s opt/apache-tomcat/bin/startup.sh tomcat
```

Apache tomcat starts but when it `forks` or something in the `startup.sh` script upstart think the process has died and keeps trying to respawn until the respawn limit is hit.

Is there anyway in the upstart script to make sure it will track the correct tomcat `PID`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct way to start tomcat and keep track of the PID. You don't want to use `startup.sh` but instead `catalina.sh` and have the following in the upstart script.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat
#exec sudo -u tomcat
script
    exec >/root/Desktop/test.debug 2>&1
    exec su -s /bin/bash -c "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run" tomcat
end script
```